# Coverage in category theory

Tags: category-theory

In this page they define
[coverage](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coverage) as

Definition 2.1. A coverage on a category $C$ consists of a function assigning to each object $U \in C$ a collection of families of morphisms $\left\{f_{i}: U_{i} \rightarrow U\right\}_{i \in I}$, called covering. families, such that

- If $\left\{f_{i}: U_{i} \rightarrow U\right\}_{i \in I}$ is a covering family and $g: V \rightarrow U$ is a morphism, then there exists a covering family $\left\{h_{j}: V_{j} \rightarrow V\right\}$ such that each composite $g h_{j}$ factors through some $f_{i}$
  $$
  \begin{array}{cccc} 
  & V_{j} & \stackrel{k}{\longrightarrow} & U_{i} \\
  h_{j} & \downarrow & & \downarrow f_{i} \\
  V & \stackrel{ }{\longrightarrow} & U
  \end{array}
  $$
  The logic here is: $\forall f, \forall g, \exists h, \forall j, \exists i, \exists k,=.$

Are this $U_i$ objects of the category $C$?

Comment: Sure. The morphisms $f_i:U_i \rightarrow U$ and in particular their domains $U_i$ are to be taken from the category $C$…

Comment: It will be often the case that you want this morphisms to have some specific properties, like being open inclusions or etale covers or something. So of cause then you might as well say that they are taken from the subcategory of $C$, consisting of all the morphisms satisfying the requirements. But of cause it doesn’t really matter if you say „open inclusion in $C$“ or „morphism in the subcategory of open inclusions in $C$“…

Comment: What else could they possibly be?